# Formula of ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

In my textbook the formula of an ellipse is noted as $$b^2  x^2 + a^2  y^2 = a^2  b^2$$

Now I have a formula that goes $$x^2 + 4y^2 = 17$$

How is this formula valid, as $1\cdot 4$ does not equal $17$?

*Edit: I just realized that if:
$$nx + my = nm$$
and
$$2x + 4y=8$$
and multiply the equation by 2 to get $$4x + 8y = 16$$
while this is true: $$2*4=8$$
this doesn't work anymore because we multiplied n and m separately on the left side and together on the right:
$$4*8 = 16$$
I literally suck and Im out of here...*

Comment: HINT: Multiply your equation by a suitable number $t$ such that the new equation matches the given pattern. For instance, in the given example $t=17/4$.

Comment: $b^2x^2 + a^2y^2 = a^2b^2 \iff \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is one way to describe an ellipse centered at origin with $x$- and $y$-axes as symmetric axes. In this representation, the parameter $a$ and $b$ has specific geometric meaning: they are the semi-major and semi-minor axes of the ellipse. However, this is not the only way to describe such an ellipse. If you multiple both sides of above equation by same non-zero number, you obtain other valid representations of the ellipse.

Comment: @AzulShiva Yes exactly, when multiply the expression, on the LHS you add $2$ factors but only one at the RHS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let divide by $17$ to obtain

$$x^2 + 4y^2 = 17 \iff \frac{x^2}{17} + \frac{4y^2}{17} = 1$$

then note that $$\frac{4}{17}=\frac{1}{\frac{17}4}$$

then

$$\frac{x^2}{17} + \frac{4y^2}{17} = 1 \iff \frac{x^2}{17} + \frac{y^2}{\frac{17}4} = 1 \iff \frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{17})^2} + \frac{y^2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{17}}2\right)^2} = 1$$

which is the form you are looking for with $a=\sqrt{17}$ and $b=\frac{\sqrt{17}}2$, indeed as noticed in the comments we have that

$$b^2x^2 + a^2y^2 = a^2b^2 \iff \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

are equivalent equations for an ellipse centered at origin.

Comment: still dont get it. If b^2 is 1/17 and a^2 is 4/17 and (a^2)(b^2) is 1 then 1/17 multiplied with 4/17 is not 1. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @AzulShiva Putting in this form $b^2x^2 + a^2y^2 = a^2b^2$ we have $$\frac{17}4 x^2+17y^2=\frac{17^2}4$$

Comment: ah we have to multiply with 17/4. Ok I get it.

Comment: @AzulShiva I don't like the form $b^2x^2 + a^2y^2 = a^2b^2$, I prefer the canonical form $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. You are welcome! Bye